# Can't install scsh on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, package-management

In trying to install scsh (*not* ssh and *not* csh) - the Scheme Shell - on Ubuntu 15.10, I keep running into dependency errors and it won't let me do it:

```
emd@luna:~$ sudo apt-get install scsh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 scsh : Depends: scsh-0.6 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
emd@luna:~$
```

Looking at what my installed system knows about scsh, I get:

```
emd@luna:~$ sudo apt-cache search scsh
scsh - A `scheme' interpreter designed for writing system programs (default version)
scsh-0.6-doc - Documentation for scsh, "The Scheme Shell"
scsh-common-0.6 - A `scheme' interpreter designed for writing system programs
scsh-doc - Documentation for scsh, "The Scheme Shell"
scsh-install-lib - scsh package installer
scsh-0.6 - A `scheme' interpreter designed for writing system programs
```

And about scsh-0.6 I get:

```
emd@luna:~$ sudo apt-cache show scsh-0.6
Package: scsh-0.6
Priority: extra
Section: universe/interpreters
Installed-Size: 8148
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Scheme48 Maintainers Task Force <pkg-scheme48-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Version: 0.6.7-8
Replaces: scsh (<= 0.6.6-3)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11), scsh-common-0.6 (= 0.6.7-8)
Suggests: scsh-0.6-doc
Conflicts: scsh (<= 0.6.6-3)
Filename: pool/universe/s/scsh-0.6/scsh-0.6_0.6.7-8_i386.deb
Size: 2996714
MD5sum: d736fabde3780e1fbab357ff12999887
SHA1: 97824c4f80f90e722b2be2fc0c77335fad293ed2
SHA256: c73e54f75506a431cd1672534b1760495a690b8688aee779410cead6fd395789
Description-en: A `scheme' interpreter designed for writing system programs
 Scsh has a high-level process notation for doing shell-script like
 tasks: running programs, establishing pipelines and I/O redirection.
 Scsh embeds this process notation within a full implementation of
 Scheme, a minimal and clean dialect of the Lisp programming language.
 The process notation is realized as a set of macro definitions, and
 is carefully designed to allow full integration with standard Scheme
 code. Scsh isn't Scheme-like; it is Scheme.
 .
 At the scripting level, scsh also has an Awk design, also implemented
 as a macro that can be embedded inside general Scheme code.
 .
 Scsh additionally provides the low-level access to the operating
 system normally associated with C. The current release provides full
 access to POSIX, plus important non-POSIX extensions, such as
 complete sockets support. "Full access to POSIX" means: fork, exec &
 wait, sockets, full read, write, open & close, seek & tell, complete
 file-system access, including stat, chmod/chgrp/chown, symlink, FIFO
 & directory access, tty & pty support, file locking, pipes, select,
 file-name pattern-matching, time & date, environment variables,
 signal handlers, and more.
Description-md5: 8ff47bffe440b87548670b2020e9a4db
Homepage: http://www.scsh.net/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

And looking at the policy for scsh I get:

```
emd@luna:~$ sudo apt-cache policy scsh-0.6
scsh-0.6:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.6.7-8
  Version table:
     0.6.7-8 0
        500 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ wily/universe i386 Packages
```

Looking at the source mirror URL, I see the following valid URLs:

1. http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scsh-0.6/scsh-0.6_0.6.7-8_i386.deb
2. http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scsh-0.6/scsh-0.6-doc_0.6.7-8_all.deb
3. http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scsh-0.6/scsh-common-0.6_0.6.7-8_all.deb

Trying to install those as a block (manually after downloading) - I get this:

```
emd@luna:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i scsh*
Selecting previously unselected package scsh-0.6:i386.
(Reading database ... 220195 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack scsh-0.6_0.6.7-8_i386.deb ...
Unpacking scsh-0.6:i386 (0.6.7-8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package scsh-0.6-doc.
Preparing to unpack scsh-0.6-doc_0.6.7-8_all.deb ...
Unpacking scsh-0.6-doc (0.6.7-8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package scsh-common-0.6.
Preparing to unpack scsh-common-0.6_0.6.7-8_all.deb ...
Unpacking scsh-common-0.6 (0.6.7-8) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of scsh-0.6:i386:
 scsh-0.6:i386 depends on scsh-common-0.6 (= 0.6.7-8).

dpkg: error processing package scsh-0.6:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up scsh-0.6-doc (0.6.7-8) ...
Setting up scsh-common-0.6 (0.6.7-8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.6) ...
Processing 3 added doc-base files...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 scsh-0.6:i386
```

My question is: *How do I install scsh fully?*

A secondary question is: *How do I resolve this sort of problem when it comes up? What further investigation can I do?*

*Update:* (more information)

Looking at scsh-common, I see this:

```
emd@luna:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-cache show scsh-common-0.6
Package: scsh-common-0.6
Priority: extra
Section: universe/interpreters
Installed-Size: 1908
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Scheme48 Maintainers Task Force <pkg-scheme48-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Source: scsh-0.6
Version: 0.6.7-8
Replaces: scsh (<= 0.6.6-3)
Suggests: scsh-0.6-doc
Conflicts: scsh (<= 0.6.6-3)
Filename: pool/universe/s/scsh-0.6/scsh-common-0.6_0.6.7-8_all.deb
Size: 378248
MD5sum: e75d6b286a8490482bc410f32601e24e
SHA1: 3ee3fe160efe72d999f8dda1665163db725dc9f1
SHA256: ba74ac8d9dae76e988bdc60054b808f3a6e6a175c7d00724560187a2729870a8
Description-en: A `scheme' interpreter designed for writing system programs
 Scsh has a high-level process notation for doing shell-script like
 tasks: running programs, establishing pipelines and I/O redirection.
 Scsh embeds this process notation within a full implementation of
 Scheme, a minimal and clean dialect of the Lisp programming language.
 The process notation is realized as a set of macro definitions, and
 is carefully designed to allow full integration with standard Scheme
 code. Scsh isn't Scheme-like; it is Scheme.
 .
 At the scripting level, scsh also has an Awk design, also implemented
 as a macro that can be embedded inside general Scheme code.
 .
 Scsh additionally provides the low-level access to the operating
 system normally associated with C. The current release provides full
 access to POSIX, plus important non-POSIX extensions, such as
 complete sockets support. "Full access to POSIX" means: fork, exec &
 wait, sockets, full read, write, open & close, seek & tell, complete
 file-system access, including stat, chmod/chgrp/chown, symlink, FIFO
 & directory access, tty & pty support, file locking, pipes, select,
 file-name pattern-matching, time & date, environment variables,
 signal handlers, and more.
 .
 This package contains the architecture-independent files.
Description-md5: b67b8d361914d72dc0e5b30aaca2650b
Homepage: http://www.scsh.net/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

The installation process is marked by dpkg this way:

```
emd@luna:~/Downloads$ dpkg -l | sed -n '1,5p; /scsh/p'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                                        Version                                    Architecture Description
+++-===========================================================-==========================================-============-===============================================================================
iU  scsh-0.6:i386                                               0.6.7-8                                    i386         A `scheme' interpreter designed for writing system programs
ii  scsh-0.6-doc                                                0.6.7-8                                    all          Documentation for scsh, "The Scheme Shell"
ii  scsh-common-0.6                                             0.6.7-8                                    all          A `scheme' interpreter designed for writing system programs
```

Only differences I see is that the package scsh wants scsh-common-0.6:i386 but the provided package is scsh-common-0.6:all... but that shouldn't matter should it?

Also, I'm also running:

```
emd@luna:~/Downloads$ cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="15.10 (Wily Werewolf)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 15.10"
VERSION_ID="15.10"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
emd@luna:~/Downloads$ uname -a
Linux luna 4.2.0-23-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Sun Dec 27 17:47:31 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: `dpkg -i` (unlike `apt-get`) doesn't attempt to resolve dependencies - it's usual (I think) to have to run `apt-get -f install` after in order to fix things. HOWEVER since it's trying to install an i386 package, the list of dependencies may be extensive: I'd suggest running it with the `-s` (simulate) or `--dry-run` flag and then deciding whether you really want to proceed.

Comment: You're right... though if you look, my first code block above is `apt-get` failing to find dependencies. I had to use `dpkg -i` to install the packages generated by the source build (detailed below in my answer). Not sure if I had to run `apt-get -f install` but I may have.

Answer (score 1):

I did more research on this problem, and found an Ubuntu [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/scsh-0.6/+bug/496062) listed against scsh on this topic. This bug references a Debian [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=414931) on the topic. The problem is that there is no scsh-0.6 build on the amd64 platform. There is no direct scsh 64-bit build. The "fix" (as shown in the Debian bug report) is to recompile the code, forcing it to compile for ia32 despite running on amd64. This breaks other code, but when you need it, you need it.

It took a few tweaks to get the source to build properly with Wily (the patches are against older versions).

After building the deb files, install them with:

```
dpkg -i scsh*.deb
```

And finally, add /usr/bin/scsh:

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s scsh-0.6 scsh
```

(Why this last step isn't automated, I have no idea.)